# Multi-threading within a JBoss Web service

Tags: web-services, jboss, executorservice

## **How can I invoke a query on multiple databases at the same time and wait for their results to return?**

**Setting**

I'm using JAX-WS and JBoss 7 to provide a web service. My service invokes a query on multiple databases, combines their results and returns all the results combined to the caller.

[image: Setting]

**What I've done so far**

I have a working client and server (except that the server doesn't retrieve any results from the databases, but I'll get back to that). In the `init` method of my code, I create an `ExecutorService` that I reuse and to which I submit `Callable`s (that do the query and return the results from the database). 
These `Callable`s perform the database query and return results.

**Problem**

My `Future`s return null (and I guess I haven't made any other mistakes). In addition to that, I read somewhere that you shouldn't use your own `ExecutorService` within a web service deployed on JBoss.

**Question**

How to solve the problem then? How can I invoke the query on multiple databases at the same time and wait for their results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using own threads is not advisable in JBoss. I found a few solutions to that:

- don't use JBoss, use e.g. the Java Endpoint interface. There you are be able to do everything manually - this means, however, that you miss the nice features coming with JBoss
- use Oracle Glassfish and its new ManagedExecutorService, see e.g. [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/create_managedexecutorservice_managedscheduledexecutorservice_managedthreadfactory_contextservice) for a nice example
- use BPEL (Business Process Execution Language) to orchestrate multiple/parallel processes, see e.g. [here](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/bpel/v1.1/userguide/) for some examples